# PostgreSQL restore error when there is a generated column in PGv13.14

Tags: database, postgresql-13

We are having issue with restore some DBs to postgres v13.14 when there are tables with "Generated Column (stored)".

So we suspect that it is something to do with the lastet postgres version 13.14. Can someone please assist ?

Steps we did as follows

Back up a DB from pg_dump v13.14 from DB server(v13.14) Restore using psql to same or another DB server(v13.14) . There is error coming when creating a table which has a Generated Column (stored) saying that relation does not exist(checking the existance of another table). This generated column has a dependecy with another two tables which creates after this table according the SQL command order in the dump file.

We do not get this error when restoring to the postgres version 13.12 ,
13.11 or below in the same major version.